# Change default direction of rotation

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, auto-rotation

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S5 for AT&T with Android 5.0.
When I run a game which runs on landscape mode, 
the default rotation is the top of the screen goes left and the bottom is right.
If I rotate the phone, then I can change the direction so that the bottom side of the phone becomes left and top-side to be right.
But I want to set the default so that bottom is left and top is right.
How can I do this?

Comment: @GrantDavis I don't think you responded seriously. Did you misunderstand my question?

Comment: No I was being silly. Hence the :P